# Emacs not starting on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, emacs

I've been using win32 emacs on windows 7 pretty regularly for the past year almost... however it has suddenly stopped working. When I execute 'runemacs', nothing happens. I can see the process has begun in the task manager, but the CPU & memory usage are unchanging.

I haven't added any new software etc... there are no network paths in my $PATH environment variable.

I've even deleted the init.el file, to no avail.

Is there a way to start emacs in a debug mode to see where it could be getting stuck?

Thanks,
Arjun

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the -debug-init flag on the command line. Though, I don't know if this will work in windows.

Other thoughts, I have a feeling runemacs.exe might be trying to run emacsclient or one of the other exe's in the bin directory. Try running emacs.exe directly instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any debugger if You are familiar with it(like olly). Also, you can try to rollback the OS to time when it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
emacs -no-init-file
```

to see if the problem is caused by something in your .emacs

also

```
emacs --debug-init
```

to see if you get any debug output

If that doesn't help try

```
emacs --nw
```

to see if it's display related

Finally, and I think this may be it, try to run as administrator (right click runemacs.exe in explorer and choose run as administrator) to see if there is a problem with file permissions. Windows 7 is a lot more fussy about file access in the Program Files (x86) folder for example.